# My Website Won't Align Properly On Zoom In and Out

Tags: html, css, alignment, positioning

I'm new to creating websites and can't seem to find out why the alignment of my website doesn't work properly.

On all three of my computer monitors, the website looks fine:

http://www.spectanium.com

But I looked at it on my one friends computer and it looked wrong.

I have a main body and then space on both the right and left, but depending on the monitor I use, there has been varying space and it looks bad...

Can anyone take a look at my code and see what I'm doing wrong?

index.html -->

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spectanium Studios</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />
    </head>


<body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>


    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
                <a href="http://www.spectanium.com/">Homepage</a><li><a href="/Spectanium%202/products.html">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Spectanium%202/aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="content">




         <div id="updatesCol">
                <h2>Recent Updates</h2>
                <h3> * Website Created *</h3>
                <p></p>
                <p style="font-size:small">Website is now done!</p>
         </div>

        <div id="contentCol">
                <h2>Welcome to Spectanium!</h2>
                <p>
                    <em>So far we have to do a few things before we are ready to roll!</em>
                </p>



                    <h3>Game Stuff:</h3>
                    <ol>
                    <li>Finish the actual game.</li>
                    <li>Get final graphics.</li>
                    <li>Get final music.</li>
                    <li>Find out distribution method.</li>
                    </ol>
                    <h3>Website Stuff:</h3>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Write descriptions for about us.</li>
                        <li>Improve it</li>
                        <li>Make it pretty</li>
                    </ol>


        </div>



  <div style="clear: both;"></div>

</div>


<div id="footer">
    <p></p>
  <p> Â© 2014 Spectanium Studios</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

default.css -->

```
body {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: black;
        background-image:url('images/background.png');
        background-size:100%;
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
        width:190%;
    font: normal "Courier New", Courier, Courier, sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    color: #B13413;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
}

p, ul, ol, blockquote {
    margin-top: 0;
}

a:link {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3284B5;
}

a:hover {
    border: none;
}

img {
    border: none;
}

/* Header */

#header {
    width: 890px;
    height: 273px;
        margin: 4px 0 4px 300px;
    background: url(images/header.png) no-repeat;

}


/* Menu */

#menu {

    background: url(images/topborder.png) repeat-x;
    width: 950px;
    height: 41px;
    margin: 0 auto;
        margin-left:275px;
        background-color: #a1a1a1;

}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
        text-decoration:none;
}


#menu li {
    display: inline;
        text-decoration:none;

}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 15px 20px 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
        font-weight:bold;
        border-bottom: 0 dotted #DDDDDD;



}

#menu a:hover{
         height:8px;
         color: #B13413;
}

/* Content */

#content {

    background: url(images/bottomborder.png) repeat-x;
    width: 950px;
        background-color: white;
        margin-left:275px;
        height: 1000px;
}

#updatesCol {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
        height:1000px;
        border-left:1px black solid;
        text-align:center;

}

#contentCol {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
        margin-left:25px;


}


/* Footer */

#footer {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
        margin-left:275px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: smaller;        
    background: url(images/bottomborder.png) repeat-x;
        clear:both;
}

#footer * {
    color: #666666;
}
```

Comment: It is looking good for me...

Comment: It is? 0.o maybe it was something wrong on the 3 other computers I tried... hmpf

Comment: Is this Problem just to one browser or to all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it's displaying to me, running on 1920x1080.

http://s30.postimg.org/s3w6clowg/hello.jpg

Problem is your backgorund. It's set to repeat-y but the width it's 1450, so it will repeat-y but won't extend further than that.

Also it'll look a bit to the left because you set all the margins in pixels, like the header:

4px 0 4px 300px .
So no matter what it'll be pushed from the left to the right of 300px. If my resolution is high it'll show a huge gap on the RIGHT side of the page.

Comment: How can I set it so instead of it being the fixed 4px 0 4 px 300px to be a static centered alignment that adjusts w/ resolution?

Comment: use margin: 0 auto; and remove also the many margins-left you have in the divs

Comment: In addition to this your blackened area in the image is not centered.

Comment: I removed the old image, I'm going currently just using a black-background.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using margin-left to align the whole website so when it scales up it is still aligned to the left. Use margin: 0 auto; to center your website. If you want the website to stay aligned to the left like it currently is however then use a percentage instead. You probably should also set a background color or having a repeating background to avoid the black background when the page is wider than your background image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
body{
  background-position-x:center;
}

body > div{
  margin:auto !important;
}
```

Now the content is centered I assure you. But it won't feel centered as the blackened area in the background-image you are using is not centered horizontally. You can see the green line is longer than the red line. Correct that and you're good to go.
My suggestion is that you use an image on background which doesn't have blackened area and achieve that by css
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have specified a absolute margin-left which is causing the problem. 
I changed some parts of your css file  and it works fine for me.

basically replace absolute margins with

```
margin-left:auto
margin-right:auto
```

**Changes in default.css**

```
body {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: black;
        background-image:url('http://www.spectanium.com/images/background.png');
        background-size:100%;
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
        width:100%;
    font: normal "Courier New", Courier, Courier, sans-serif;
}

#header {
    width: 890px;
    height: 280px;          
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background: url(http://www.spectanium.com/images/header.png) no-repeat;

}
#menu {

    background: url(http://www.spectanium.com/images/topborder.png) repeat-x;
    width: 950px;
    height: 51px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
        background-color: #a1a1a1;

}
#content {

    background: url(images/bottomborder.png) repeat-x;
    width: 950px;
        background-color: white;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        height: 1000px;
}
/* Footer */

#footer {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
        margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: smaller;        
    background: url(http://www.spectanium.com/images/bottomborder.png) repeat-x;
        clear:both;
}
```